# How to get the list of the users who have access to the shared drive with google api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I would like to obtain the list of the users who have access to the specific shared drive with Google API(drive or admin SDK).
Hasn't Google supported the such API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

See Google Drive for Developers v3 [Permissions:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)